# Change label on required select date widget in django

Tags: django, forms, widget

So I want to change the label on my select date widget on django, preferably to the current date, but even just saying "Month" "Year" etc would suffice. I dont want it to just say "January 1 1980" as is the default. I know that to use the empty_label in my widget, my field has to be blank, or not required, in my model. However, my field is required, but I want the field to match another non-required widget. Here is my form code:

```
class AnimalForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Animal
    fields = ['animal_id','species_strain','dob', 'dod', 'sex', 'source', 'parents', 'labloc', 'notes']
    widgets ={
                "dod":forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1980,2050), empty_label=("Year", "Month", "Day")),
                "dob":forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1980,2050), empty_label=("Year", "Month", "Day")),


    }
```

For clarification, dob is required while dod is not. But I want them to at least look the same on the webpage. If possible, I would LOVE to make the default value the current date, but I need to be able to at least edit the fields first. So how can I do this? I've tried googling it to no avail. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetimepicker from datepicker-plus it will provide you with the current time and the current date.You can follow this link  https://github.com/monim67/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus

Answer (score 0):

You can supply an `[initial][1]` value to the form via

```
f = AnimalForm(initial={
    'dod': datetime.today(),
    'dob': datetime.today(),
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much! So I'm getting a " module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today' error, but I think once this is fixed it should work! Ive imported datetime, am I missing something else to import?

Comment: You likely need `from datetime import datetime`. In any case, that was just to show how you'd get the dates generically. You probably would want to use `from django.utils import timezone` and then `timezone.now().date()`